# How to write a validators function that should accept the value between 0 to 30 but not decimal value ?? in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

that the if user enter the value between 0 to 30
it should accept 0 ,2, 20 and but should not accept decimal value like 20.1 , 0.1

I have use validators min(0) and validators max(30) but it accept the decimal value
Need a validators that should not accept decimal value

If have to use regex pattern, can you give regex pattern code to ??

Comment: Use pattern with regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pattern validator along with min and max. You can also use a single pattern with min max numeric range but then you won't be able to put different error messages for each. Here we are using 3 validators one for min, one for max and pattern to check only digits:

```
const control = new FormControl(0, [Validators.min(0), Validators.max(30), Validators.pattern('[0-9]+')]);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Creating a custom validator

Creating a custom validator in Angular is done by implementing the [ValidatorFn Interface](https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidatorFn)

**Creating a validator that only accepts whole numbers 0 through 30**

So in order to implement the interface we see we need a function which takes an abstract control, and returns null on no errors, or a dictionary of key-values if there are errors, which gives us the following:

```js
export const myNumberValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl) => {
  if (Math.floor(control?.value) != control?.value || control?.value < 0 || control?.value > 30)
    return {"INVALID_NUMBER": "Number must be a whole number between 0 and 30"}
  return null
}
```

[See On Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ctz2os?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex pattern validation for this.

```
^(3[0]|[12][0-9]|[1-9])$
```

You can register your custom validators on the form.

[image]

[Working demo on Blitz here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-regex-custom-validator-ryyxm2?file=src/app/app.component.html)